# TLS 1.2 No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for RSA key

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I get signature algorithm issue during CertificateVerify for TLS 1.2, not sure why it happens and how to fix it.

It would be much appreciate if someone could share some suggestions, thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more information.

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.59
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.3.0-1035-azure
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_275-b01
JVM Vendor:     Amazon.com Inc.

Error Logs:
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|3C|http-nio-8080-exec-9|2021-09-06 19:09:37.559 GMT+08:00|Logger.java:765|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for RSA key ( 
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               "throwable" : { 
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for RSA key  
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)    
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)    
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)   
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)   
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)   
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyMessage.<init>(CertificateVerify.java:597)    
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:760)  
9/6/2021, 11:09:37.560 AM               at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with a combination of your JRE and the used certificate.

I had this exact same message using JRE 11 with OpenLiberty trying to load a JKS Keystore that included another PKCS12 keypair.

In the end I was able to resolve this just by upgrading the execution environment to JRE 17.